# How to work with wordpress theme Customize API while using timber/twig

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

I am using timber/twig to create wordpress themes, and I want the users to have the ability to select header images from the Theme Customize menu. So I used the Wordpress Customization API. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

However, it seems timber/twig having some conflicts with the API. The theme sections did not show up in the menu while I am using timber, but the exactly code would work in a generic WordPress theme.

I am not quite sure where to start? Am I missing anything?

Comment: What you need is an additional admin page. This, however, has nothing to do with Twig or Timber. But you could try Metabox.io for simple solutions. You can install the needed metabox plugins via composer if thats how you build things.

Comment: ah! thanks for the hints!

Comment: It seems Timber did something to the Wordpress theme customize api. I could manipulate the theme customize api in a generic wordpress theme, but it did not work with timber. Am I missing something? @dsasko

Comment: For me the customize API works fine with Timber. But you can't call it the way you usually did before, rather you call it using the function method. Example: {{ function('get_theme_mod', 'name') }}

Comment: This goes for practically all wordpress functions you want to call from your themes template file (twig file). Also, I think that get_theme_mod will not get the default values, you need to change and publish them first.